# How to archive data stored in HDFS files on another (non-distributed) server?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, parquet, cloudera-cdh

I have a project folder containing approx. 50 GB of **parquet files** on a **hadoop cluster** (**CDH 5.14**), which I need to **archive** and **move** to **another host** (**non-distributed** with Windows or Linux). This is only a **one time job** - I do not plan to bring the data back to HDFS any time soon, however there should be a way to **deploy it back** to a distributed file system. What would be the optimal way to do it? Unfortunately, I don't have another hadoop cluster or a cloud environment where I could place this data.
I would appreciate any hints.

Answer (score 1):

The optimal solution can depend on the actual data (e.g. Tables, many/few flat files). If you know how they got in there, looking at the inverse could be a logical first step.

For example, if you just use `put` to place the files,  consider using `get`.

If you use Nifi to get it in, try Nifi to get it out.

After the data is on your Linux box, you can use SCP or something like FTP or a mounted drive to move it to the desired computer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! In general these data files are taken from huge csv files converted to parquet for fast distributed processing in Spark. Actually, I might consider using NiFi for this archiving, but I am still not sure which format to use - zipped csv might be still too big for an archive...